# My Fonts get changed after refreshing about page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, fonts

When I go to [this](http://www.stitchstudio.co/about/) page from home page. It shows proper font. But when I refresh this page its font gets changed.

Please see the screenshots:

[image: Screenshot of the about page of stitch studio]

Comment: It looks like you have some problem with the CSS on your homepage setting your font but it's getting lost when accessing one of the child pages independently. Without more information it is difficult to diagnose. Please update your question with more information in order for someone to help you.

Answer (score 0):

check your browser console there is font error means fonts not found

```
GET http://www.stitchstudio.co/about/fonts/DINNextLTProBold.woff2 
GET http://www.stitchstudio.co/about/fonts/DINNextLTProRegular.woff 
GET http://www.stitchstudio.co/about/fonts/DINNextLTProBold.woff 
GET http://www.stitchstudio.co/about/fonts/DINNextLTProRegular.ttf 
GET http://www.stitchstudio.co/about/fonts/DINNextLTProBold.ttf 
GET http://www.stitchstudio.co/wp-content/themes/lens/theme-content/css/fonts/DINNextLTProRegular.woff2 
GET http://www.stitchstudio.co/wp-content/themes/lens/theme-content/css/fonts/DINNextLTProRegular.woff 
GET http://www.stitchstudio.co/wp-content/themes/lens/theme-content/css/fonts/DINNextLTProRegular.ttf 404 (Not Found)
```

check path and fix it then it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are not pointing to the theme directory in the right way, you should use get_stylesheet_directory_uri() or similar.

```
<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/font-folder/font.extension
```

right now, it's not using it, so from homepage, font gets loaded because it points to: 
http://www.stitchstudio.co/fonts/DINNextLTProRegular.woff2

for other pages it is not, and it will use page url, not site url, just like: 
http://www.stitchstudio.co/about/fonts/DINNextLTProRegular.woff2

causing the error.